# Python dictionary weird behavior in mrjob

Tags: python, dictionary, mrjob

I'm writing a code that reads two input files and calculates some statistics like average rating by country. I'm using mrjob library, because the idea is that I'm able to run this on hadoop. Below are samples from those input files.

Users file:

```
"1";"nyc, new york, usa";NULL
"2";"stockton, california, usa";"18"
"3";"moscow, yukon territory, russia";NULL
"4";"porto, v.n.gaia, portugal";"17"
"5";"farnborough, hants, united kingdom";NULL
```

Ratings file:

```
"276729";"0521795028";"6"
"276733";"2080674722";"0"
"276736";"3257224281";"8"
"276737";"0600570967";"6"
"276744";"038550120X";"7"
```

The first column in the both files is user ID, so I need to use the user IDs to combine the data somehow.

Below is the code that I have written

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.protocol import TextValueProtocol
import os

class BookRatings(MRJob):

    INPUT_PROTOCOL = TextValueProtocol
    OUTPUT_PROTOCOL = TextValueProtocol

    # This mapper function yields key value pairs
    # user_id, country or user_id, rating
    def mapper(self, _, line):

        if os.getenv('mapreduce_map_input_file') == "file://Users.csv":
            # I'm using try because we might find some lines that are
            # badly formed, which causes IndexError
            try:
                # If we are reading the User file, we separate user_id and country
                csv_separation = line.split(";")
                user_id = csv_separation[0].strip('"')
                country = csv_separation[1].split(",")[2].strip().replace('"', '')

                yield (user_id, country)
            except IndexError:
                pass
        else:
            try:
                csv_separation = line.split(";")
                user_id = csv_separation[0].strip('"')
                rating = csv_separation[2].strip('"')

                yield (user_id, rating)
            except IndexError:
                pass


    def combiner(self, user_id, value):

        # I could only come up with this method to build a dictionary
        # which I could use in reducer to calculate statistics
        user_country_mappings = {}
        user_rating_mappings = {}

        for v in value:

            # So i'm checking if value is a number, because I want to create
            # two dictionaries, one in which there's a country under user_id key
            # and another in which there's a list of ratings under user_id key
            if v.isdigit():
                try:
                    user_rating_mappings[user_id.strip()].append(v)
                except KeyError:
                    user_rating_mappings[user_id.strip()] = [v]
            else:
                user_country_mappings[user_id.strip()] = v

        # last thing in combiner I want to have only one dictionary, which has
        # country names as keys, and each key's value is a list which contains
        # all ratings given by a user from that country      
        ratings_by_country = {}

        # So, I loop over dictionary that contains user_id, ratings value pairs
        for k,v in user_rating_mappings.items():

            # I want every individual value from rating list
            for rating in v:

                # I add each rating to my new dictionary, and I get the country name
                # from user_country_mappings dictionary, using the same user_id as key
                try:
                    ratings_by_country[user_country_mappings[k]].append(v)
                except KeyError:
                    ratings_by_country[user_country_mappings[k]] = [v]

         # Then finally I yield this ratings_by_country dictionary
         yield (None, ratings_by_country)

    # Reducer should yield the final result
    def reducer(self, _, mappings):

        # Now at this point though I'm just trying to yield
        # every key value, just to test that everything has worked so far
        for value_map in mappings:
            for k,v in value_map.items():
                yield(None, k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BookRatings.run()
```

So, the code gives the following error.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/ratings.py in combiner(self, user_id, value)
     62                 try:
---> 63                     ratings_by_country[user_country_mappings[k]].append(v)
     64                 except KeyError:

KeyError: '10'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/ratings.py in <module>
    143 
    144 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 145     BookRatings.run()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in run(cls)
    444         # load options from the command line
    445         mr_job = cls(args=_READ_ARGS_FROM_SYS_ARGV)
--> 446         mr_job.execute()
    447 
    448     def execute(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in execute(self)
    471 
    472         else:
--> 473             super(MRJob, self).execute()
    474 
    475     def make_runner(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py in execute(self)
    200     def execute(self):
    201         # Launcher only runs jobs, doesn't do any Hadoop Streaming stuff
--> 202         self.run_job()
    203 
    204     def make_runner(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py in run_job(self)
    245         with self.make_runner() as runner:
    246             try:
--> 247                 runner.run()
    248             except StepFailedException as e:
    249                 # no need for a runner stacktrace if step failed; runners will

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/runner.py in run(self)
    515         self._add_input_files_for_upload()
    516         self._create_input_manifest_if_needed()
--> 517         self._run()
    518         self._ran_job = True
    519 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py in _run(self)
    158             self._counters.append({})
    159 
--> 160             self._run_step(step, step_num)
    161 
    162     def _run_step(self, step, step_num):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py in _run_step(self, step, step_num)
    167             self._run_step_on_spark(step, step_num)
    168         else:
--> 169             self._run_streaming_step(step, step_num)
    170 
    171     def _run_streaming_step(self, step, step_num):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py in _run_streaming_step(self, step, step_num)
    178                 self._input_paths_for_step(step_num), step_num)
    179 
--> 180             self._run_mappers_and_combiners(step_num, map_splits)
    181 
    182             if 'reducer' in step:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py in _run_mappers_and_combiners(self, step_num, map_splits)
    219                 self._run_mapper_and_combiner_func(
    220                     step_num, task_num, map_split)
--> 221                 for task_num, map_split in enumerate(map_splits)
    222             )
    223         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py in _run_multiple(self, funcs, num_processes)
    127         """
    128         for func in funcs:
--> 129             func()
    130 
    131     def _log_cause_of_error(self, ex):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py in _run_mapper_and_combiner(run_mapper, sort_input, run_combiner, mapper_input_path, mapper_output_path, combiner_input_path)
    727     if run_combiner:
    728         sort_input([mapper_output_path], combiner_input_path)
--> 729         run_combiner()
    730 
    731 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/sim.py in _run_task(invoke_task, task_type, step_num, task_num, input_path, output_path, stderr_path, wd, env)
    744 
    745         invoke_task(
--> 746             stdin, stdout, stderr, wd, env)
    747 
    748 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/inline.py in invoke_task(stdin, stdout, stderr, wd, env)
    130 
    131                     task = self._mrjob_cls(args)
--> 132                     task.execute()
    133                 except:
    134                     # so users can figure out where the exception came from;

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in execute(self)
    462 
    463         elif self.options.run_combiner:
--> 464             self.run_combiner(self.options.step_num)
    465 
    466         elif self.options.run_reducer:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in run_combiner(self, step_num)
    555         read_lines, write_line = self._wrap_protocols(step_num, 'combiner')
    556 
--> 557         for k, v in self.combine_pairs(read_lines(), step_num=step_num):
    558             write_line(k, v)
    559 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in combine_pairs(self, pairs, step_num)
    625         .. versionadded:: 0.6.7
    626         """
--> 627         for k, v in self._combine_or_reduce_pairs(pairs, 'combiner', step_num):
    628             yield k, v
    629 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py in _combine_or_reduce_pairs(self, pairs, mrc, step_num)
    664         for key, pairs_for_key in itertools.groupby(pairs, lambda k_v: k_v[0]):
    665             values = (value for _, value in pairs_for_key)
--> 666             for k, v in task(key, values) or ():
    667                 yield k, v
    668 

~/ratings.py in combiner(self, user_id, value)
     63                     ratings_by_country[user_country_mappings[k]].append(v)
     64                 except KeyError:
---> 65                     ratings_by_country[user_country_mappings[k]] = [v]
     66 
     67 

KeyError: '10'
```

So, I studied the given error and figured out what triggers the exception. I tried what happens if I put that problem part in another try except block, and after that the code finished, but the dictionary was empty.

Then I did check what user_country_mappings and user_rating_mappings dictionaries looked like, and they looked exactly what I expected them to be. They both had user_ids as keys, and one dictionary had country name as a value and the other had a list of ratings. At this point I verified that they have common keys, for example that '10', and they both did have it. But somehow this combiner function raises KeyError, claiming that user_rating_mappings key is not in user_country_mappings. From the very beginning, I think I'm handling the values identically, so I can't see why KeyError is raised. I tried similar structure in Python interpreter on command line, and everything worked just fine.

At this point I'm clueless why the code behaves like it does. Any help is appreciated, thanks!